# CS50 Speller, passes the test but check50 issue, uninitialized values used

Tags: c, cs50

I just finished cs50 Speller, and the code passes all the other test, but it kept telling me "you're trying to use a 8-byte variable that might not have a value" on the "while" line of the code for the spelling checking part.

I've seen other people's answer about this problem but I still didn't know why I am having the problem.

Makefile

```
speller:
    clang -fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -Qunused-arguments -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow -c -o speller.o speller.c
    clang -fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -Qunused-arguments -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow -c -o dictionary.o dictionary.c
    clang -fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -Qunused-arguments -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow -o speller speller.o dictionary.o
```

speller.c

```
// Implements a spell-checker

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Undefine any definitions
#undef calculate
#undef getrusage

// Default dictionary
#define DICTIONARY "dictionaries/large"

// Prototype
double calculate(const struct rusage *b, const struct rusage *a);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check for correct number of args
    if (argc != 2 && argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: speller [dictionary] text\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Structures for timing data
    struct rusage before, after;

    // Benchmarks
    double time_load = 0.0, time_check = 0.0, time_size = 0.0, time_unload = 0.0;

    // Determine dictionary to use
    char *dictionary = (argc == 3) ? argv[1] : DICTIONARY;

    // Load dictionary
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    bool loaded = load(dictionary);
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // Exit if dictionary not loaded
    if (!loaded)
    {
        printf("Could not load %s.\n", dictionary);
        return 1;
    }

    // Calculate time to load dictionary
    time_load = calculate(&before, &after);

    // Try to open text
    char *text = (argc == 3) ? argv[2] : argv[1];
    FILE *file = fopen(text, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", text);
        unload();
        return 1;
    }

    // Prepare to report misspellings
    printf("\nMISSPELLED WORDS\n\n");

    // Prepare to spell-check
    int index = 0, misspellings = 0, words = 0;
    char word[LENGTH + 1];

    // Spell-check each word in text
    for (int c = fgetc(file); c != EOF; c = fgetc(file))
    {
        // Allow only alphabetical characters and apostrophes
        if (isalpha(c) || (c == '\'' && index > 0))
        {
            // Append character to word
            word[index] = c;
            index++;

            // Ignore alphabetical strings too long to be words
            if (index > LENGTH)
            {
                // Consume remainder of alphabetical string
                while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF && isalpha(c));

                // Prepare for new word
                index = 0;
            }
        }

        // Ignore words with numbers (like MS Word can)
        else if (isdigit(c))
        {
            // Consume remainder of alphanumeric string
            while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF && isalnum(c));

            // Prepare for new word
            index = 0;
        }

        // We must have found a whole word
        else if (index > 0)
        {
            // Terminate current word
            word[index] = '\0';

            // Update counter
            words++;

            // Check word's spelling
            getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
            bool misspelled = !check(word);
            getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

            // Update benchmark
            time_check += calculate(&before, &after);

            // Print word if misspelled
            if (misspelled)
            {
                printf("%s\n", word);
                misspellings++;
            }

            // Prepare for next word
            index = 0;
        }
    }

    // Check whether there was an error
    if (ferror(file))
    {
        fclose(file);
        printf("Error reading %s.\n", text);
        unload();
        return 1;
    }

    // Close text
    fclose(file);

    // Determine dictionary's size
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    unsigned int n = size();
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // Calculate time to determine dictionary's size
    time_size = calculate(&before, &after);

    // Unload dictionary
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    bool unloaded = unload();
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // Abort if dictionary not unloaded
    if (!unloaded)
    {
        printf("Could not unload %s.\n", dictionary);
        return 1;
    }

    // Calculate time to unload dictionary
    time_unload = calculate(&before, &after);

    // Report benchmarks
    printf("\nWORDS MISSPELLED:     %d\n", misspellings);
    printf("WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  %d\n", n);
    printf("WORDS IN TEXT:        %d\n", words);
    printf("TIME IN load:         %.2f\n", time_load);
    printf("TIME IN check:        %.2f\n", time_check);
    printf("TIME IN size:         %.2f\n", time_size);
    printf("TIME IN unload:       %.2f\n", time_unload);
    printf("TIME IN TOTAL:        %.2f\n\n",
           time_load + time_check + time_size + time_unload);

    // Success
    return 0;
}

// Returns number of seconds between b and a
double calculate(const struct rusage *b, const struct rusage *a)
{
    if (b == NULL || a == NULL)
    {
        return 0.0;
    }
    else
    {
        return ((((a->ru_utime.tv_sec * 1000000 + a->ru_utime.tv_usec) -
                  (b->ru_utime.tv_sec * 1000000 + b->ru_utime.tv_usec)) +
                 ((a->ru_stime.tv_sec * 1000000 + a->ru_stime.tv_usec) -
                  (b->ru_stime.tv_sec * 1000000 + b->ru_stime.tv_usec)))
                / 1000000.0);
    }
}
```

dictionary.c

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents number of buckets in a hash table
#define N 26

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1]; //LENGTH = 45
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Represents a hash table
node *hashtable[N];//pointer 
node *current[N], *previous[N];

// Hashes word to a number between 0 and 25, inclusive, based on its first letter
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    return tolower(word[0]) - 'a';
}

//for hash table
int j;

//for counting 
unsigned int count;

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // Initialize hash table
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        hashtable[i] = NULL;
    }

    // Open dictionary
    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        unload();     //？
        return false;
    }

    // Buffer for a word
    char word[LENGTH + 1];

    // Insert words into hash table
    while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF)       {
        j = tolower(word[0]) - 'a';

        if (hashtable[j] == NULL)
        {
            hashtable[j] = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

            if (hashtable[j] == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: unable to allocate required memory\n");
                return 1;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++) 
            {
                (*hashtable[j]).word[i] = word[i]; 
            }

            (*hashtable[j]).next = NULL;

            previous[j] = hashtable[j];

            //clear the array "word"
            for (int i = 0; i < (LENGTH + 1); i++)
            {
                word[i] = '0';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            current[j] = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

            if (current[j] == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: unable to allocate required memory\n");
                return 1;
            }

            (*previous[j]).next = current[j];

            for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)
            {
                (*current[j]).word[i] = word[i];
            }

            (*current[j]).next = NULL;

            previous[j] = current[j];

            //clear the array "word"
            for (int i = 0; i < (LENGTH + 1); i++)
            {
                word[i] = '0';
            }
        }

        //count the number of words in dictionary
        count++;
    }

    printf("%d", count);

    // Close dictionary
    fclose(file);

    // Indicate success
    return true;
}



// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    return count;  
}

// Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // TODO

    //point current back to the start of linked list
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        current[j] = hashtable[j];
    }

    int i = tolower(word[0]) - 'a';

    while (strcasecmp(word, current[i]->word) != 0)  //the problem occurs here!
    {
        current[i] = (*current[i]).next;

        if(current[i] == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{
    // TODO
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        current[j] = hashtable[j];
    }

    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        while (current[j] != NULL)
        {
            previous[j] = current[j];
            current[j] = (*current[j]).next;
            free(previous[j]);
        }
    }

    return true;                                
}
```

If I passes other test of check50, it means I have created the hash table successfully and it checks spelling properly, then why am I still having the "you're trying to use a 8-byte variable that might not have a value" problem? Every (*current[i]).word in the while loop should be initialized. Hope someone can help me about it, thank you.

Comment: Use `current[i]->word` instead of `(*current[i]).word`.  It's far easier to understand.

Comment: There is no way anyone can answer without seeing the complete code with declarations and initializations. How do you expect us to tell if a variable isn't initialized when you don't show the initialization code?? Post a [mcve].

Comment: @Lundin sorry this is the first time I asked a question on Stack overflow, I have added more of my code on this post, if it's still unclear for you to understand the problem, plz let me know! Thank you~

Comment: There are missing closing `}` from your function. `hashtable`, `current`, `previous` definitions is missing.

Comment: Well, now `while (strcasecmp(word, current[i]->word) != 0)` is in another function, in another code flow... You have to show how and when do you call `bool check(const char *word)` function. The goal is to analyze, if any of the `word, current[i]->word` can be uninitialized before entering this function. For that we need a complete flow of what happens to `current` and `word`. If we call `check()` function before initializing `hashtable`, then `current[i]->` is dereferencing a null pointer... also `int i = tolower(word[0]) - 'a';` may be invalid `current` index. What is the definition of `N`?

Comment: @KamilCuk sorry I want to make my code minimal to read but I think I'll just put all the code up so that you can have a clearer look at it, thank you!

Comment: You have some character encoding problems in the code itself. This happens when you do something fishy like writing source code in MS Word. What code editor are you using?

Comment: Anyway, I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Lundin I am using AWS

Comment: `#define N 26` - well, can `int i = tolower(word[0]) - 'a';` be greater then `26`? Does the error go away if you add `assert(i < 26)` or similar?

Comment: What's the actual error message?

Answer (score 0):

`strcasecmp` takes two strings as arguments. Remember the thing that makes a string a string: the terminating null byte. For instance, this loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++) 
            {
                (*hashtable[j]).word[i] = word[i]; 
            }
```

does *not* terminate node.word with a null byte. Make sure that wherever a node.word is "created" that it becomes a real string by terminating it properly.

Comment: You are right ! I used strcmp() instead of my previous way and it worked! You really helped me a lot, thank you~